# How do I prevent the Windows 2008 logon screen from showing user account names?

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, configuration

When I logon to Windows 2008 via the console or via RDP it shows me the names of user accounts already created as clickable buttons.

How do I prevent this and make Windows 2008 ask me for a username that must be typed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to set this in the group policy editor (Run: gpedit.msc) under:

Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > System > Logon

Set it to use the classic login screen.  This will work if the server is standalone.  If it is part of a domain, it will follow this policy as set by the domain policy instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the server is standalone and not a member of a domain, then you can achieve the result you desire by performing any of the 3 options below:

1. Enable the **Interactive logon: Do not display last user name:** setting in the **Local Security Policy** snap-in (secpol.msc).
2. Change the registry value **dontdisplaylastusername** to 1 for the following key:

   **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System**
3. Run the following PowerShell command:

   ```
   Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -Name dontdisplaylastusername -Value 1 -Type DWORD
   ```

All steps above are detailed [here](http://www.vsysad.com/2015/01/login-screen-displaying-multiple-accounts-on-windows-server-2008-r2/). Please note that the link is a post on my blog.

If the server is a member of a domain enable the same policy in a GPO (Group Policy Object) and apply it to the relevant server(s) then run gpupdate /force on the relevant server(s) or reboot them to effect the change.